# Python: best way to dynamically read folder structure and create list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this root `folder`:

```
C:\hw
```

And under this root path I have this folders `structure`:

```
C:\hw\ios
    C:\hw\ios\10
    C:\hw\ios\11
    C:\hw\ios\12
    C:\hw\ios\13
    C:\hw\ios\14
C:\hw\android
    C:\hw\android\9
    C:\hw\android\9.0.1
```

And I want to read all `folders` into `list` of lists (only first level):

```
dict = {
            'ios': ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
            'android': ['9', '9.0.1]
        }
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-traverse-a-directory-tree-in-python-guide-to-os-walk/ and many others.  You are expected to do some research and present our solution with questions, should you have any.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
import glob
import os

os.chdir("../")

tree = {}

joiner = "\\*\\" # Change this to /*/ if you are on Mac OS or on Linux

folders = glob.glob(os.getcwd() + joiner) 

for folder in folders:
    tree[folder] = glob.glob(folder + joiner)

print(tree)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {}
>>> BASE_DIR = "."
>>> for file in os.listdir(BASE_DIR):
...     if os.path.isdir(BASE_DIR+file):
...             d[file] = os.listdir(BASE_DIR+file)
```

If you want add only files in that directory then, you can put an extra condition of file check `os.path.isfile()`